# Efficient division using binary math

Tags: number-theory, boolean-algebra, binary

I'm writing code for an FPGA and I need to divide a number by $1.024$.  I could use floating and/or fixed point and instantiate a multiplier but I would like to see if I could do this multiplication more efficiently.

I noticed that $2^0$ + $2^-$$^6$ + $2^-$$^7$ = $1.0234375$ which is 99.95% of $1.024$; well within my tolerance requirement.  It feels like there is some way I can take advantage of this fact to divide a number by $1.0234375$ (essentially $1.024$) without having to do costly multiplication but I'm stuck on where to go from here.  I've seen similar types of things done by early game developers to speed up their calculations and this is essentially what I'm trying to accomplish here but instead of maximizing speed I want to minimize FPGA utilization.

Comment: Isn't $2^0 + 2^6 + 2^7 = 193$??

Comment: @nbubis Thank you, I left out the proper signs, fixed

Comment: Not sure what the efficient operations are for FPGAs, but if you can support shifting and addition then $x / 1.024$ is the same as $125x/128 = x - \text{shiftright}(x, 5) + \text{shiftright}(x,7)$.

Comment: Isn't multiplication cheap on most hardware? Division's the one that tends not to be.

Comment: @dfeuer True but certainly still more expensive than an proper adder.  But not sure about this utilization vs execution speed...maybe it's roughly total number of operations regardless whether they're parallel or sequential.

Comment: @ErickWong This is exactly what I'm looking for. If you could create a bonafide answer that explains how you came up with your answer I will certainly accept it.  Thank you!

Comment: How big is the number you want to divide?

Comment: @mj9973 It's a <+/-,32,7> Fixed Point data type.  That is to say a signed fixed point with 32 bits for the word length and 7 bits for the integer portion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{1.024}  = \frac{1024-24}{1024} = \left(\frac{1024 - 16 - 8}{1024}\right)$$

So to divide N,

$$ N*\left(\frac{1000}{1024}\right) = ((N << 10) - (N << 4) - (N << 3)) >> 10 $$

You need 2 adders. Shift operation will be free in FPGA as all are powers of 2. If you want to use fraction of the result, simply use lower 10 bits of the addition. For FPGA specific questions, you can always try electronics.SE

Comment: Thank you, shifting is exactly what I'm looking to do because as you say, it's a free operation in FPGA.

Comment: Just a bit of an update.  Using this trick I was able to save two DSP48 multipliers from being used.  Considering this FPGA only has 68 of them, that is significant to me.

Comment: @SiegeX, that's cool.

Comment: Nice to hear, @SiegeX!  I just wanted to add that the first line is unnecessarily modest: the left and right end-values are *exactly* equal so there's no need for the intermediate approximations.

Comment: @ErickWong You are right. Its cleaner this way.